# How much run-time stack can be assumed in Android JNI?

Tags: android, java-native-interface

My app makes a `JNI` call in an `AsyncTask`. The `activity` would crash (or somehow be terminated) on Android 4.0, but is ok on later versions.

Eventually, I tracked it down to a possible stackoverflow(!) in the `JNI`. One of my routines put 4K on the C stack (not recursive). Once I took this out of the stack, everything worked.

My question is, how much can generally be assumed, can it be configured or changed and does anyone know the reliable limits for various API versions.

My theory is that additional threads like `AsyncTask` are given a lot less than the main UI thread, which is why this doesn't often bite.

thanks for any info.